# In hierarchical model, how to choose groups that meet exchangeability, automatically?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

In hierarchical model, we assume exchangeability. For example,
y[i] ~ Norm(b0 + b1[groups[i]], sigma) and
b1 ~ Norm(mu_b1, sd_b1)


above, all groups are assumed exchangeable. But, it might be better model:
for(i in 1:3) b1[i] ~ Norm(mu_b1a, sd_b1a) 
for(j in 4:9) b2[j] ~ Norm(mu_b2a, sd_b2a) 

but it is tiresome to change and try groupings many times. So, how can I automatically choose which group belong to same category?
Though I can do that if some work like k-means or pca beforehand for finding category, I want to do both at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider Bayesian model averaging between all possible models with combinations is groups that are exchangable with each other. There are various ways of doing this. E.g. [directly](https://doi.org/10.1002/pst.1730) or e.g. using horseshoe priors.

Comment: Thank you! I am appreciated. EXNEX is new idea to me. I will search it.